# Make Div Clickable which has backgorund video in autoplay loop mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

There is an autoplay loop background video inside a `div`. I want to make the whole element clickable. When I am wrapping the anchor tag around the div or the video, the video does not play anymore. Can someone tell how to make the div clickable without changing the behaviour of the video? Also we need to keep in mind not to hamper the performance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add some code to clarify your question. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

use Jquery's  .click  and put your code functionality inside it i.e. whatever you want to happen after clicking the video put it inside the .click

moreover add css to your video div so that a cursor is changed to the pointer that will indicate the video is clickable.

```js
$("#your_video_id").click(function() {

  //whatever you want to do after clicking it

});
```

```css
  #your_video_id:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
```